# What is model variable everywhere in yii application? and why 'model' variable name?

Tags: php, yii

What is the `model` variable in the below code, what is it used for and can i use other variable names?

```
    $model=new Post;
    if(isset($_POST['Post']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Post'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

can anybody tell me what the `model` variable is ?

Comment: The variable could be named `$post` or whatever is relevant/informational. However, the render method might need the 'model' key for it's own binding; if this is the case, then using `$model` might add consistency to the name.

Comment: 'model' is the object of your model(Post) class. It is passed to view pages for getting the attributes name of that model for creating input elements..

Comment: The usage is basic PHP usage and is not related to Yii. If you are having problems understanding this code you might also have issue understanding other Yii code. I will suggest you review the PHP documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

You can find the model attributes via:

```
var_dump($model->attributes);
```